# how to add google adsense?

Tags: android, adsense

i am using this code which looks perfect without any error bt dont know why my application gets crashed everytime i run my app..

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId= "idthatigotthroughadmob"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
/>
```

in android manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

in

```
<application><activity
 android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
 ></activity> </application>
```

logcat shows

```
04-12 21:30:09.655: E/dalvikvm(272): Could not find class 'com.google.ads.AdView', 
referenced from method com.project.hisaabkikitaab.MainActivity.onCreate
04-12 21:30:09.655: W/dalvikvm(272): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 471 (Lcom/google
/ads/AdView;) in Lcom/project/hisaabkikitaab/MainActivity;
04-12 21:30:09.655: D/dalvikvm(272): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000e
04-12 21:30:09.655: D/dalvikvm(272): VFY: dead code 0x0010-02b9 in Lcom/project  
/hisaabkikitaab/MainActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
04-12 21:30:09.815: D/AndroidRuntime(272): Shutting down VM
04-12 21:30:09.815: W/dalvikvm(272): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught     
exception  (group=0x4001d800)
04-12 21:30:09.845: E/AndroidRuntime(272): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 21:30:09.845: E/AndroidRuntime(272): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    
com.google.ads.AdView
04-12 21:30:09.845: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at    
com.project.hisaabkikitaab.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
04-12 21:30:09.845: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at   
.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `ads` namespace to the layout root node, too

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

The tutorial where you probably took the example from already has it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" 
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals, Android tab

Another possible solution:

Is there a `libs` folder in your project? If so, is there the `admob` library? In case you say no to any of those, make sure a `libs` folder is created (at the same level of `res` and `src`, and copy your `admob` library there. Clean project and rebuild.

Comment: i have already added that :( <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backmage"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

Comment: i have written my code through that developers page you are reffering bt dont know what is happening my app gets crash everytime i start .. is there is anything more that i am missing??

Comment: @scripter Try this: is there a `libs` folder in your project? If so, is there the `admob` library? In case you say no to any of those, make sure a `libs` folder is created (at the same level of `res` and `src`, and copy your `admob` library there. Clean project and rebuild.

Comment: yes i have libs folder bt not that admob library just one more 1 thing how to paste that admob library???

Comment: thanks man finally i added admob in libs and it's working great :)

Answer (score 0):

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner

build.gradle (app)

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.1.0'
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    .....
   <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
</application>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/adView"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  ads:adSize="BANNER"
  ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

In MainActivity

```
private AdView mAdView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });

    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
    
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
   
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
    
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClicked() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
    
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sign in to your AdSense account.
On the AdSense home page, click Add site.
Enter the URL of the website where you want to show ads. Blogger, YouTube or other hosting partner. ...
Click Save. Note: If you own multiple sites, you can also add them now.